# C - how can a pointer be checked for the memory having been freed from another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Suppose I have 2 pointers to the same object.

```
int * a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 5;
int * b = a;
free(a);
a = NULL;
```

At this point I know that `a == NULL` but b is still pointing to that address that has been freed. Is it possible to know *through b* that the memory has been freed?

The scenario is that I am running unit tests and I want to make sure that some structs are freed at the right time under the right conditions and so I would like to avoid having to add infrastructure just to support testing.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What's your motivation for doing this? You could create a structure to contain this and add a `has_been_freed` flag.

Comment: @ggorlen I will add a little more info so you can see why I won't add more infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. Long answer: definitely not :-)

There are tricks you can implement, such as the use of doubly-indirect pointers (an allocated structure that contains the *pointer* to the actual back-end data)<sup>(a)</sup>, this is basically how smart pointers work in C++ and I've seen them implemented in C before<sup>(b)</sup>. These are much more complex than raw pointers in that they may require mutex-protected reference counts, and all usage to *only* go through the API.

But the code manipulating these pointers may not necessarily *be* your code so, if you pass the back-end pointer through to some function that frees it *without* going through your API, all bets are off. In addition, it adds an extra level of indirection expense to every access.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A simple example of this (no reference counting) is along the lines of:

```
pointerA      +---------------+    +-------------+
        >---> | smart pointer | -> | actual data |
pointerB      +---------------+    +-------------+
```

All access is indirect via the smart pointer, which can be set to NULL when *either* of `pointerA` or `pointerB` is "freed". Hence, if you free `pointerA`, then try to use `pointerB`, the value you get will be NULL.

This requires an API for creating and destroying the smart pointers, getting and setting the back-end raw pointer, and so on.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> [GObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject), for example, is a partially reference-counted variant using smart pointers in C. It forms the basis of the object model in Gtk and GStreamer.

Early versions of Windows, *long* before protected mode when there was no memory management hardware (I'm revealing my age there !) used a similar double-indirect scheme so it could move memory around at will without all the processes ending up with invalid pointers.